# Openning vmx files doesn't work in vmware workstation

Tags: vmware

I currently use VMware Workstation 15.5 Pro.
the problem is that when I open vmx files, it shows nothing.
It was okay after I excueted VMware Workstation with administrator grant but, it has randomly been unable to open vmx files.
what should I do? thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean when you say it shows nothing ?